# would (*abc) + 15 be undefined since the array is only 10 chars long?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I am preparing for an interview and I wanted to solve this problem since I've seen it in different scenarios:

```
Char abc[10] ; 
Strncpy(abc,”abcdefghijklmn”,10);
```

What are the data types and values of below

```
Abc ->abcdefghij
*abc -> char a
Abc[5] -> char f 
Abc+4  -> char e
&abc[5] -> address of char f ?
(*abc)+15 -> undefined ?
```

next to each line you have my answer . Did i do it correctly? if not..can you pls help out ?

EDIT: Yeah guys I copied the problem from a document hence the bad formatting. I did not bother using lowercase.. thanks for input ! The (*abc) + 15 makes sense now. Not sure why I thought it would go over. It's clearly character 'a' + 15. Thanks !

Comment: OMG: (*abc)+15 will be 'a' + 15

Comment: Which could potentially cause an overflow of `char`, though I'm not quite sure what the deal is with overflow for `char` in relation to `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

Comment: `*(abc+15)` is what you described, same as `abc[15]`

Comment: Unless you're talking about some non-standard function, it's spelled `strncpy`, not `Strncpy`. And see [here](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html) for reasons *not* to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abc ->abcdefghij
```

Correct. Note that the array is not null terminated, so should not be passed to functions which operate on c-strings.

```
*abc -> char a
abc[5] -> char f
```

Correct.

```
abc+4  -> char e
```

No. It is the address of the `e` character.

```
&abc[5] -> address of char f ?
```

Correct.

```
(*abc)+15 -> undefined ?
```

No. It is the value of the character `a`, converted to an integer, and incremented by 15. Assuming a character set (such as all of the most common ones) in which the letters of the English alphabet are laid out sequentially, then it is the code for 16th lowercase letter of that alphabet, p. In most cases, this will be the number 112.

Comment: "It is the value of the character a, converted to an integer, and incremented by 15" -- Why is it converted to an integer? Does this happen with all integral types smaller than `int`?

Comment: @leemes: Because of the addition. Any binary operator on types smaller than `int` causes both operands to be converted to `int` before the operation takes place.

Answer (score 0):

Neat interview question. I would go with:

```
Abc -> &abc[0] which points to 'a'
*abc -> *(&abc[0]) = 'a'
Abc[5] -> *(&abc[5]) = 'f' 
Abc+4  -> &abc[4] which points to 'e'
&abc[5] -> address of char 'f' ?
(*abc)+15 -> *(&abc[0]) = 'a' + 15 = 'p'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many typos.:) it seems that you copied and pasted this test from MS Word.:)
Instead of

```
Char abc[10] ; 
Strncpy(abc,”abcdefghijklmn”,10);
```

there shall be

```
char abc[10] ; 
strncpy( abc, "abcdefghijklmn", 10 );
```

Again instead of

```
Abc ->abcdefghij
```

there shall be

```
abc ->abcdefghij
```

Take into account that now array abc is not zero terminated.

As for this statement

```
(*abc)+15 -> undefined ?
```

then it is simply to get its value. You already wrote that

```
*abc -> char a
```

So in the first expression `( *abc )` can be substituted for its value `'a'` and you will get

```
'a' + 15 -> 'p'
```

More precisely the value of the expression 'a' + 15 will be an object of type `int` which value corresponds to the ASCII code of character 'p'.

Also this expression

```
abc+4  -> char e
```

is equivalent to

```
&abc[4]
```

that is its value is the addres of 'e' in the array

```
abc+4  -> address of char e
```